# Gettext php - how to translate this value?

Tags: php, gettext

I need to implement Gettext. If I have to translate

```
<p>Title: </p>
```

I can use the following:

```
<p><?php _e("Title: ","language");?></p>
```

Which is pretty simple for single word of sentences in PHP files. However how can I implement the above Gettext if in PHP I have already

```
<?php  the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
```

?

What I would like to translate is the word "Tags: "... but I can't figure out how to wrap the work "Tags"... or how to change the code...

Thanks

Comment: _“What I would like to translate is the word "Tags: "”_ – and that does not work in the same way as it does with the word _Title_ _because_ …?

Comment: @CBroe I am looking how to write the right Gettext for "Tags". I was thinking that something like the_tags(__"('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />')", "language"); ... but I don't think it works like this....

Comment: If `_e("Title: ","language")` translates the term `Title: ` to your satisfaction, then what code would probably do the same for the term `Tags: ` …?

Comment: If tags was out of PHP code and was like `<p>Tags: </p>` then it would have been `_e("Tags: ","language")`. But in this case I have `the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />');` and I don't know how to edit that the right way, thus I decided to write here.

Comment: Well, `_e` is for direct output of a translation, and `__` is its counterpart to only get the translation as a return value, so that it can be used within other functions. But in your code line you mentioned in your comment you are passing nonsense parameters to it.

Comment: nonsense parameters? They do have a sense 'the_tags( $before, $sep, $after );'. See here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags it displays a list of the tags with a line break after it.

Comment: I meant parameters for the `__` function. (But you are not even actually calling that within the shown code, because that would require a `(` after the function name.)

Comment: I think I found the answer to my question... it seems that the right code I have to use is `the_tags(__('Etykiety: ','language'), ', ', '<br />');`